# Title not being rendered with LaTeX

Tags: latex

So I have the following document:

```
\include{preamble}


\title{test title}

\begin{document}


\maketitle



\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \pi\sqrt{\pi\sqrt{\pi\sqrt{\pi\sqrt{\pi\sqrt{\pi\dots}}}}}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
    



\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

the contents of my preamble.tex file is:

```
%%%%% Document Setup %%%%%%%%

\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn]{revtex4}    % Font size (10,11 or 12pt) and column number (one or two).


\usepackage{times}                          % Times New Roman font type
  
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.85cm, right=1.85cm,top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm]{geometry}       % Defines paper size and margin length

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}                      % Defines caption font size as 9pt and caption title bolded


\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,epsfig,ulem}  % Makes sure all graphics works 
\usepackage{amsmath}            % Adds mathematical features for equations

\usepackage{etoolbox}                       % Customise date to preferred format
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{)}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\Dated@name{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}        % Position reference section correctly
    





\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}       
\usepackage{xcolor}
  
  
\newcommand{\incfig}[2][1]{%
    \def\svgwidth{#1\columnwidth}   
    \import{./figures/}{#2.pdf_tex} 
}

\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
```

For some reason the title just will not be included on the pdf when I compile the code, I am sure I have \title{} and \maketitle in the correct positions. Any help as to why this is would be much appreciated.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but the `times` package is obsolete. Instead have a look at the `mathptmx`, `helvet` (option scaled=.9) or `courier` packages

Comment: If you already load `graphicx`, you don't need `graphics`

Comment: also don't load the same package multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the title after `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}   

\begin{document}

\title{test title}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

(don't do this with other documentclasses. Most of the time it is better to have the `\title` in the preamble, e.g. to get sensible pdf meta data if combined with hyperref)